# How to mathematically determine the number of odd numbers between two integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

Is there a formula that states the number of odd numbers between two integers like $1$ and  $10$, or in general between $1$ and $x$?

Comment: $N_{\text{odd}}(x)=\lfloor (x+1)/2\rfloor$, where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the floor function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every other number is odd, so your function is
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x/2&\mbox{if $x$ is even};\\(x+1)/2&\mbox{if $x$ is odd}\end{cases}$$

Comment: @test Read the function carefully. Don't just copy-paste the comment you made to the other answer.

Comment: Sorry my bad :(

Answer (score 0):

One basic formula (I think) for this would be: $$\text {odd numbers between $1$ and $x$} = \left\lceil\frac {x - 1 + 1}{2} \right\rceil$$ which simplifies to $\frac x2$. The reason why is that the number of odd numbers between 1 and some number, $x$ is equal to half the amount of numbers between one and $x$. But, the only case in this won't be "true" is if $x = \infty$, because there are the same amount of odd numbers between 1 and $\infty$ and all the numbers between 1 and $\infty$.

Comment: Well.. I would have to add a ceil to it, or i would get an decimal number 
x = 31 => 15.5